# Отступы между символами в сообщении валидации html5

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Добавляю валидацию формы через атрибуты `required` и `pattern`, но символы расположены очень близко один к одному.

Как между ними сделать отступы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую такой код

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" pattern="^([\\+]{1}[3]{1}[8]{1}[0]{1})([0-9]{9})$" required title="Номер телефона в формате +380XXXXXXXXX">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Речь идет об отступах между символами? Или о готовой маске номера телефона?

Comment: Об отступах в маске номера телефона

Comment: Системное уведомление извлекается из title, поэтому вы можете его откорректировать в такой вид: "Номер телефона в формате +380 (99) 999-9999".

Answer (score 6):

Добавьте свойство `letter-spacing: 5px;` к данному блоку.

`5px` - изменяйте на своё значение.

Comment: Этот блок на прямую не могу стилизовать

Comment: @Shperung напишите в вопрос ваш фрагмент кода

Comment: Написал фрагмент кода

Comment: @Shperung воспользуетесь ответом ниже... как я понял, нельзя изменять данное окно. Единственное, это отредактировать `title="Номер телефона в формате +380 (XXX) XXX-XXX">`

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется, чтоб номер телефона разделялся определенным способом, то попробуйте данную реализацию через JS:

```js
new Formatter(document.getElementById('phone-input'), {
  'pattern': '+38 ({{999}}) {{999}}-{{9999}}',
  'persistent': false
});
```

```html
<script src="http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/javascripts/formatter.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" id="phone-input" class="m-input" placeholder="(999) 999-9999">
```

Если речь шла именно об отступе между символами во всплывающем уведомлении, то вряд ли получится повлиять на него. Насколько я понял, это системное уведомление из браузера. Но, системное уведомление извлекается из title, поэтому вы можете его откорректировать в такой вид: "Номер телефона в формате +380 (XX) XXX-XXXX".

Comment: Если ввести номер, переместиться на пару символов назад и зажать бэкспейс, то получится неплохой баг, который фризит мой браузер на пару секунд. Алсо, вопрос требовал совсем иного решения.

Comment: Существуют и другие реализации. [Вот](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=424), например. Если результат работы со скриптом вас устраивает, используйте его. К тому же, он более гибкий в эксплуатации.

Comment: да я не к тому написал. Суть в том, что это не ответ на поставленный вопрос, автору не нужен плагин маскирующий инпуты, а нужно отформатировать оповещающее окошко. Дак кроме того, плагин в ответе еще и кривой до ужаса.

Comment: Я задал автору вопрос перед тем как дать ответ. Обратите на это внимание. Речь идет именно о маске номера телефона. Ответ сейчас заменю, но лучше обратили бы внимание на свой ответ. При чем тут подсказки я так и не понял.

Comment: Мне кажется, приложенный скрин с _единственным_ окошком подсказки, где четко видно, что пространство между цифрами в маске(да, готовой тоже) стремится к нулю - должен нести некую смысловую нагрузку, нет?

Answer (score 1):

Покуда это системное уведомление браузера, и насколько мне известно, `css'ом` неизменяемое, единственный совет - юзать кастомные тултипы, `css/JS` в помощь, гуголь свербит от их изобилия.

[Линк](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag) на англоязычный СО с таким же вопросом

[Линк №2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag/2011199#2011199) - минималистичный `css` хак в ответе `valli`

Comment: в спецификации CSS3, написано, что такое исправлять можно

Comment: @Insider чудно, вставляйте ответ тогда `как, где, куда`

Comment: да вот, пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: к сожалению вы правы, изменить его нельзя

Comment: @Insider, жаль, я понадеялся на просвет уже. Сам сталкивался с подобным, увы ничего не получилось `:/`